# RSA decoded (phpseclib) JSON string throw error 3

Tags: json, phpseclib

im trying decode JSON transmitted via RSA (PHPSECLIB). This throw JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR.

```
$json_string = $rsa->decode($cyphertext);
$json_object = json_decode($json_string);
```

$json_string looks like

```
{\u0000\"\u0000k\u0000e\u0000y\u0000\"\u0000:\u0000\"\u0000W\u0000Z\u0000g\u0000...
```

json_last_error() returns 3

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

RSA Decrypt put null chars into message. You must delete them.

```
$json_string = $rsa->decode($ciphertext);  //decode my message
$json_string = str_replace("\0", "", $json_string); //replace null chars with "null" :D
$json_object = json_decode($json_string);  //decode json_string
```

Comment: Kinda looks like you're encoding a UTF-16 string and trying to decode it as US-ASCII or some such.